# Javascript null value

Tags: javascript

Javascript code assigns null value to variable "room".

```
var room = document.getElementById("roomID").value;
```

is always null

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Echo Chamber</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    </head>
    <body>

        <div>
             <label>Room ID:</label>
            <input type="number" id="roomID"/><br/><br/>
             <label>Message :</label>
            <input type="text" id="messageinput"/><br/><br/>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button type="button" onclick="openSocket();" >Open</button>
            <button type="button" onclick="send();" >Send</button>
            <button type="button" onclick="closeSocket();" >Close</button>
        </div>
        <div id="messages"></div>

        <script type="text/javascript">

            var webSocket;
            var messages = document.getElementById("messages");
            var room = document.getElementById("roomID").value;

            function openSocket(){
                if(webSocket !== undefined && webSocket.readyState !== WebSocket.CLOSED){
                   writeResponse("WebSocket is already opened.");
                    return;
                }
                console.log(room);
                webSocket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/EchoChamber/echo/" + room);

                webSocket.onopen = function(event){
                    if(event.data === undefined)
                        return;

                    writeResponse(event.data);
                };

                webSocket.onmessage = function(event){
                    writeResponse(event.data);
                };

                webSocket.onclose = function(event){
                    writeResponse("Connection closed");
                };
            }

            function send(){
                var text = document.getElementById("messageinput").value;
                webSocket.send(text);
            }

            function closeSocket(){
                webSocket.close();
            }

            function writeResponse(text){
                messages.innerHTML += "<br/>" + text;
            }

        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: On pageload, the input is empty, so `document.getElementById("roomID").value` will give you the empty string when you try to access it on pageload...

Comment: Ok i just put ```document.getElementById("roomID").value``` in the onOpen function in js and its ok, but the handshake is still unsuccesful, any ideas why? Thanks u already helped me alot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i just put

```java
document.getElementById("roomID").value
```

inside the function `openSocket()` in javascript and it works. The problem was that assigning value to a variable "room" happened outside the function 
`openSocket()`